# Proof by induction: $2(\sqrt n - 1) < \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right)$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, radicals

Need help with proof by induction for: **$$2(\sqrt n - 1) < \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt i}\right)$$**

For n=1: Good.
Assuming for n, trying to proof for (n+1)...
Thanks.

Comment: Look carefully at the homework-problem sheet you copied this problem from. Doesn't it say "prove by induction or in any other way"? So you may want to try another way.

Answer (score 1):

We can in fact prove a slightly stronger inequality, i.e.,
$$2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-1\right) < \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{i}}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

At the induction step, we need to prove that
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}} + 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) > 2(\sqrt{n+2}-1)$$
i.e., we need to prove that
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}} > 2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})$$

We have
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}} = \dfrac2{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+1}} > \dfrac2{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2}} = 2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})$$
which gives us what we want.

---

Another way is to make use of the fact that $\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is strictly decreasing and hence
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{i}} > \int_i^{i+1} \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Hence, we obtain that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{i}} > \int_1^{n+1} \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = 2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-1\right)$$